# How To rig a fat guy

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones, rigify

So I've been experimenting with the best what to rig this guy, I've re rigged him about five times already. So basically this guy is for a mobile game where you roll him around the world and if you don't keep him knocked out he will run away, so keep in mind his bones will have to be affected by physics later on. any good methods of rigging this much fat? [image]

Comment: What are your constraints for this game, are you sure you will be able to use physics? can you use modifiers? otherwise you could fake physics with bones

Comment: we have a great programmer that made awesome rag doll physics for it

Comment: there's a simple way with Mesh Deform modifier and Cloth physics, but will you be able to use it in your game? I don't think so. There's a more complicated solution that uses Cloth physics but doesn't use Mesh Deform, it is explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c11l2o5uCQs  do you want me to give a full answer?